# Unable to use strong encryption

Tags: apache-2.4

So I am exploring Apache to create a simple example: the default page and a directory "secure". I everyone to be able to access the server but, when one wants to access the "secure" directory, I the connection to use strong encryption.

I am using apache2.4.

However this is not working and I don't know why!

I have done just like in the Apache tutorial:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/vitorpereira/Desktop/cert.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/vitorpereira/Desktop/key.key
</VirtualHost>

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

<Location /var/www/html/secure>
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
</Location>
```

But this does not work :/ And, I can access the secure folder with http but when I write https, it says not found!

Comment: Is that your whole httpd.conf? (I assume not.) As it is you haven't told the virtualhost where to serve documents from.

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve? A switch between HTTP and HTTPS? If you already have an HTTPS connection it doesn't make that much sense to vary the ciphers to sometimes include weak ones.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how HTTPS normally works:

1. the browser connects to the SSL-enabled port
2. the SSL handshake happens
3. then once the secure tunnel has been established some content is requested
4. and the request satisfied.

Your problem is that you want the server to modify step 2 based on something that's not going to be known to it until step 3.

The only way that could work is if the browser told the server what content it wanted before any SSL tunnel was established - but this would remove about half the point of SSL in the first place, which is client confidentiality.

This is unlikely to be feasible.